# bluetooth device over USB using hciattach

Tags: linux, bluetooth, usb

I was using bluetooth device on UART interface, but for some reason, we changed BT device to USB interface. we used hciattach command:

```
 ./hciattach /dev/ttyS1 any 115200 flow
```

for BT device over UART.

Now we changed to USB interface. I searched in intern and found

```
./hciattach /dev/ttyUSB1 any 115200 flow
```

for BT device attach.

We don't want to use UART device, is there any way I can use directly USB devices instead of using USB device as ttyUSB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found for USB BT device case, i don't need to attach the device, as i used to do it in UART devices case (./hciattach /dev/ttyS1 any 115200). 
hciconfig identifies, device without hciattach. we just need to do "./hciconfig up" to make BT device run.
Thanks.